# Interpolation with Voronoi tessellation in sf package in R

Tags: r, r-sf, voronoi

I have cobbled together a way to use the `sf` package in R to interpolate values on a regular spatial grid using Voronoi tessellation (nearest-neighbor). I think it gives the correct result but I have the feeling that I am doing this in an inefficient way. I would like to incorporate this code into a beginner geospatial analysis lesson, so I'm trying to prioritize simple code that a beginner can understand. If anyone has any suggestions for how I can achieve this result more directly with fewer lines of code, I would be very interested in that.

### reproducible example

Define some data for interpolation, and convert to a simple feature object.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

lead <- structure(list(x = c(408164, 405915, 405724, 406703, 405392, 
                             405644, 409183, 407945, 406341, 404638, 403575, 406215, 405472, 
                             410239, 411596, 405420, 406537, 404455, 406231, 405139, 407349, 
                             406254, 406104, 405188, 406414), 
                       y = c(4762321, 4767394, 4767706, 
                             4769201, 4765598, 4762037, 4763057, 4770014, 4762603, 4767636, 
                             4767009, 4761815, 4763316, 4767923, 4766442, 4765211, 4763711, 
                             4763921, 4762146, 4760665, 4761599, 4760669, 4767885, 4765323, 
                             4768644), 
                       ID = 0:24,
                       ppm = c(3.89, 4.9, 4.43, 5.29, 5.3, 4.68, 
                               3.36, 4.1, 4.69, 5.42, 5.87, 4.61, 4.57, 4.33, 4.26, 5.67, 5.81, 
                               4.66, 5.08, 3.66, 4.36, 4.04, 4.83, 5.07, 5.7)), 
                  row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = "data.frame")

lead <- st_as_sf(lead,
                 coords = c('x', 'y'),
                 crs = 32618)
```

Do the Voronoi tessellation. This is the part that seems very roundabout to me. It is difficult to explain in beginner terms why it's necessary to do the spatial union before the tessellation. Also somewhere along the way, the order of the points is jumbled up so you need to `st_join` by `ID` to get them back in order. Is there any way to do it in fewer steps?

```
lead_voronoi <- lead %>%
  st_union %>%
  st_voronoi %>%
  st_collection_extract %>%
  st_as_sf %>%
  st_join(lead)
```

Create a regular grid of points where we want to predict the `ppm` value based on the nearest neighbor polygon each grid point is inside.
Join it to the tessellated polygons to get the interpolated value at each grid point. This part I don't have a problem with.

```
pred_grid <- st_make_grid(
  lead, cellsize = 400,
  what = 'centers')
  
pred_grid <- pred_grid %>% 
  st_as_sf %>%
  st_join(lead_voronoi)
```

Again if there is a more efficient way to do this, please let me know.

### Plot of tessellation

This shows the predicted values for each polygon, with the locations of the prediction grid points (green) and the observed values (red).

[image: tessellation plot]

Comment: I feel your pain. When I was in your shoes (writing a course and an beginner friendly article for web) I struggled with exactly this issue. This is what I came up with - a piece of code not unlike yours, plus an explanation why it was so convoluted (and necessary): https://www.jla-data.net/eng/spatial-aggregation/

Comment: Very helpful to see your approach @JindraLacko, I guess it might have to be convoluted! :-/ I like how your comments on the code explain what each step does.